# IBM ODM: Swagger not generating description for variables

Tags: jackson, swagger, ibm-odm

We recently upgraded from ODM 8.10 to ODM 8.11.

I have used *@JsonPropertyDescription* annotation to have descriptions added to variables of input and output object when generating a swagger (using the "Retrieve HTDS Description File" and OpenAPI - JSON option). The code:

```
@JsonPropertyDescription("Description here")
private String id;
```

The project code stayed the same and it doesn't seem to work in ODM 8.11 anymore. Descriptions nor default values for objects made by the user are not added to the generated Swagger. Descriptions for default variables and objects remain (such as __DecisionId__ or Error object).

Is it a bug in ODM 8.11? Or am I supposed to use different annotations?